# No output after build

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm exploring ASP. NET 5 and following some tutorial.

Im using Visual Studio 2015.

I opened Project>ASP NET Web Application>ASP NET 5 Template>Empty.

I did a simple build and it showed "Hello World"

So I added index.html in wwwroot directory

and commented out the hello world line in the **startup.cs** code

```
public class Startup
{        
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
    //    app.UseIISPlatformHandler();

    //    app.Run(async (context) =>
    //    {
    //        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World");
    //    });
    }

    // Entry point for the application.
    public static void Main(string[] args) => WebApplication.Run<Startup>(args);
}
```

Now when I build and run, i get a blank screen. It is supposed to show index.html but it is not.

EDIT : using app.UseStaticFiles(); will only work with /index.html and not in general.

*ANSWER* : **I found that all the beta version of ASPNET had** `app.UseStaticFiles();`**to serve for static file. Now that 1.0.0-rc1-final is released we have to use** `app.UseDefaultFiles();` **as well**

Comment: you want to display Hello world Using MVC ?

Comment: is there anything on index.Html to show ?

Comment: Yes index.html has basic body and text.
And no, not using MVC. Just to display a static file as of now. ( Later i'll do the MVC)

Answer (score 1):

By default the ASP.NET 5 pipeline will not serve files, even if they are in the `wwwroot` folder. You must explicitly tell it that you want static files by adding a reference to the `Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles` package and then adding the static files middleware to the pipeline:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseStaticFiles();
}
```

After that, you can navigate to `<url>/index.html` and get the expected file.

Comment: What you mentioned works fine with Web but IIS needs separate configuration with which i can run index.html without /index.html